# Как правильно прикрутить класс?

Tags: php, ооп

Решил сделать чистильщик тв-программы. Чистильщик будет иметь два режима: первый - загрузка и обработка текстовых файлов (их может быть до 30, но названия не меняются), второй - когда копируешь текст одного файла, вставляешь в `<textarea>` и получаешь результат. 
Для первого режима почти все готово и вроде пока он работает. Я сделал класс и прописал переменные:

```
public $fileName, $startTime, $endTime, $findAndDelete;
public function Raw(){...}
public function Del($array){...}
```

Здесь указаны, соответственно:

название файла для обработки, время начала тв-программы, время ее конца (остальное за пределами времен удаляется или переносится в следующий день). `Raw()` читает файлы построчно с помощью `file()` приводит к нормальному виду и возвращает массив. `Del()` удаляет все лишнее в соответствии с `$findAndDelete` из полученного массива `Raw()` и возвращает обработанный массив.

Например, для канала Discovery будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
$disc_eu_s = new Channel;
$disc_eu_s->fileName = 'disc_eu_s.txt';
$disc_eu_s->startTime = '10:00';
$disc_eu_s->endTime = '02:00';
$disc_eu_s->findAndDelete = array(
    '~с Беаром Гриллсом~u',
    '~с Эдом Стаффордом~u'
);
result( $disc_eu_s->del( $disc_eu_s->raw() ) );
```

Итак, вопрос.

***Как правильно "прикрутить" класс ко второму режиму так, чтобы оба режима обрабатывали текст одинаково вне зависимости от того, я загрузил его как файл или открыл файл скопировал и вставил текст?***

В первом режиме файлы читаются построчно и во втором режиме вставленный текст тоже будет читаться построчно `explode("\n", ...)`. Единственное, что я зря сделал, это завел переменную `public $fileName`, - она бесполезна для второго режима. Кстати, вот что еще общего у обоих режимов (что может помочь в моем вопросе) - это первая строка в файле и первая строка во вставленном тексте, - здесь указано название канала, но как здесь правильно подвязаться?

P.s Я забыл в своем вопросе обозначить один важный момент. Обработка в первом режиме происходит согласно плану, то есть, если файл disc_eu_s.txt, то время начала и конца, а также findAndDelete у него соответствующие. И если я открываю этот же файл, копирую содержимое и вставляю в textArea, то приложение (если можно так сказать) должно распознать, что это текст будто из disc_eu_s.txt и редактируется согласно его переменным. Поэтому и хотел привязаться к первой строке с названием канала...

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется в данном случае ваш класс нарушает принцип SOLID SRP. 
Получается сейчас у класса две обязанности: получение данных и их переработка в методе del.

Я бы сделал так:

1) Инкапсулировал данные в конструктор.

2) В конструктор `Channel` передавал дополнительно некий объект вместо
 `disc_eu_s.txt`

Получилось бы так:

`$disc_eu_s = new Channel(new DataFile('$fileName'),'10:00', '02:00', findAndDelete); //для режима с файлом`

`$disc_eu_s = new Channel(new DataTextArea(),'10:00', '02:00', findAndDelete);//для режима с полем. Можно передавать конструктору название поля, тут уж как вы считаете нужным.`

`$disc_eu_s->fileName` из класса убрать.

Методу `Raw()` передавать на вход объект данных, который будет вызывать его методы для извлечения строк.

```
interface idata{
public function Raw();
}

Class DataFile implements idata{
...
}
Class DataTextArea implements idata{
...
}
```

И в `DataTextArea` уже реализовывать весь функционал по обработке данных с формы.

Comment: спасибо! Php я только изучаю, об `interface` я еще не знал до вашего сообщения, но уже почитал и теперь кое-что знаю (правда, так и не нашел в каком файле хранить `interface`, там где класс или там где его экземпляры?), обязательно воспользуюсь вашим советом! Как быть с `del()`? Куда ее поместить, в `interface`?

Comment: Лучше вынести в отдельный файл в той же директории, что и файлы классов. Пока проект маленький это может показаться излишним, но когда он разрастется, то новым созданным классам может потребоваться от него наследоваться.

Comment: Я забыл в своем вопросе обозначить один важный момент. Обработка в первом режиме происходит согласно плану, то есть, если файл disc_eu_s.txt, то время начала и конца, а также findAndDelete соответствующие. И если я открываю этот файл, копирую содержимое и вставляю в textArea, то приложение (если можно так сказать) должно распознать, что это текст disc_eu_s.txt  и редактируется согласно его переменным. Поэтому и хотел привязаться к первой строке с названием канала...

Comment: `del()` оставляем там, где она сейчас. Обязанностью класса будет работать со строками полученными из тех классов и удалять то, что вам не нужно.


idata - в данном случае т.н. маркерный интерфейс. Интерфейсы не могут содержать реализации.


___
И в целом общий совет. ООП - это методология,парадигма и php не лучший язык для начала ее понимания.

Comment: Поэтому и хотел привязаться к первой строке с названием канала... – А вот это поясните. 

Вообще Ваши классы не должны знать об особенностях их использования. Все что касается переменных и особенностей использования должно решаться "выше".

Comment: Но вот в чем дело. Получается сначала массив `raw()`, потом массив `del( raw() )`, я не могу получить сначала `del()`, а потом `raw()`...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76649/discussion-between-four-and-forever-young).

Comment: Discovery Russia (Сокращенно)

`Понедельник, 30 Апреля
09:00, 23:00, 05:40 Махинаторы 12+
09:50, 10:15, 22:00, 22:30, 07:20, 07:45 Сделано из вторсырья 12+`. Так примерно всегда выглядит содержимое файла. Самая первая строка - это название файла.